# How to add image in button strictly at inset with the first line?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I am expecting to get something like this:

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

I have set insets as this:
[image]

And I am getting my button like this:
[image]
[image]

How do I correct the inset when I button detects a two line text.

Comment: There is no code involved here. It is just storyboard.

Comment: You can use UIControl to better for this UI.

Comment: If your design UI is different from your running time UI, maybe you are using different  simulators than the device in your IB. like one is iPhone 8 plus while the other is iPhone 8.

Comment: using button for this UI may result padding in button's dynamic text, so I would suggest to use `UILabel` & give image top according to label's top & for action you can use tapGesture